# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to fetch mean value from set of images in a directory but this error comes while running.

Pls help me out to solve this,below is the code

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
path = "C:\Users\Karanths\Desktop\Images1\Hasa1"
files=os.listdir("C:\Users\Karanths\Desktop\Images1\Hasa1")
means=[]
i=0
for f in files:
 fname=path+f
 img=cv.imread(fname,0)
 avg=np.mean(img)
 means.append(avg)
 np.savetxt("means.txt",means)
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: error means you try to calculate `None/some_number`. Use `print` to see what you have in variables. Maybe you have `None` instead of expected values. Check `img` - probably it can be `None` if `imread` can't read image. You don't check `fname` type - it can be folder, not file - so you can try to read folder.

Comment: for f in files? What's files?

Answer (score 0):

`imread()` can read only images.

If you try to read different file format or folder then you get `img = None` and then you have `np.mean(None)` so you get your error.

You have to check `img` before you use `np.mean(img)`

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

means = []

path = "C:\\Users\\Karanths\\Desktop\\Images1\\Hasa1"

files = os.listdir(path)

for name in files:
    fullname = os.path.join(path, name)

    img = cv.imread(fullname, 0)

    if img is not None: # `if img:` doesn't work because it can be numpy array which works different
        avg = np.mean(img)
        means.append(avg)
    else:
        print('Unknow file format:', name)

np.savetxt("means.txt", means)
```

Comment: Yup it works, thank you very much for your kind help. Looking more support from you. Thank you again.

Comment: Whether it is the case with all the versions of python, open cv or it differs?? Because when I tried with other system the above code worked fine.